# JavaScript/jQuery: Can´t get "WWW-Authenticate" response header

Tags: javascript, jquery, http-headers, httpresponse, digest-authentication

I have following jQuery-code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url,
  complete: function( data ){
    console.info( data.getResponseHeader("WWW-Authenticate") );
  }
});
```

Which will return null. In Firebug I can see, that the header "WWW-Authenticate" is sent by the server.

Is there any way to get the header? If I can see it in Firebug, then it should be possible to get it in jQuery.

I already tried stuff like:

```
beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "withCredentials", true );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "WWW-Authenticate" );
    xhr.setRequestHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "WWW-Authenticate" );
  }
```

If I try:

```
data.getAllResponseHeaders()

// Returns:
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html
```

But in Firebug, I see WAY more headers... a lot more.

Thank you very much!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using CORS requests it's normal to see all other header data in firebug, but in your xHR object you will see just few of them (content type, last-modified, language, expires, pragma and cache control)

You may play around and try to add this to your server response (if you have access to it) by sending **Access-Control-Expose-Headers** take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin) for more details.